# My code isn't working. Do I need to use a loop?

Tags: ruby

Code is not working and I have no idea why. I thought it looked good. Maybe I dont understand the language yet and need a loop for the words.each and redacted.each part? Ruby is hard!
Thanks for the help!

```
puts "Write something: "

text = gets.chomp
text.downcase!

puts "Redact some words: "

redact = gets.chomp
redact.downcase!

words = text.split(" ")
redacted = redact.split(" ")

redacted_text = ""

words.each do |word|             #I think the problem happens starting here
redacted.each do |wordtoredact|
unless redacted.include?(word)
  puts "No redactable word(s) found."
end
do
  if word == wordtoredact       #is this right?
    redacted_text = redacted_text + "REDACTED "
  else
    redacted_text = redacted_text + "#{word}"
  end
end
puts redacted_text
```

EDIT: The point of this code is to take a string as an input and redact certain words.Then reprint the original string with the redacted words.
EDIT2: I made comments where I think may be the problem.
EDIT 3: Here is what happens when I put in these two inputs:

```
 Write something: 
 hello my name is Bob
Redact some words: 
hello bob
No redactable word(s) found.
No redactable word(s) found.
No redactable word(s) found.
No redactable word(s) found.
No redactable word(s) found.
No redactable word(s) found.
REDACTED hello my my name name is is bob REDACTED
```

Why does no redactables occur if there ARE redactable words there? And how come the redacted_text object prints every word twice. Is something wrong with my looping mechanism?

Comment: Would you mind adding some information about what it is you're trying to achieve with your code? That would be helpful for getting you a solution to your problem. Since I don't know the outcome I can't really say if this code will help you get what you truly want.

Comment: I don't think ruby is "hard". Do you have experience programming in a different language? IMO ruby is just different from everything else and beautiful in it's own way. It just takes a little time to get used to ;)

Comment: I appreciate the inspiring words. ^_^ But I'm still really stuck :(

Comment: CLUE 1: Your `words.each{|word|}` does nothing. You have to put code **inside** the brackets if you want to perform it for each word.

Comment: Ok your clue really helped! My code compiles now, but it does something really weird. I've edited the question. =D

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are a little confused about block syntax.  Check out [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby-for-newbies-iterators-and-blocks--net-17089) reference.

I believe this is what you're trying to accomplish. For some reason, everything in Ruby is easier than it seems at first :D

```
puts "Write something: "
text = gets.chomp.downcase          # I chained downcase here. It's simpler :D

puts "Redact some words: "
redact = gets.chomp.downcase        # Here too, same reason

words = text.split(" ")
redacted = redact.split(" ")

redacted_text = ""

words.each {|word|      # Check for each word if it should be redacted
        if redacted.include?(word)
            #It should, redact it!
            redacted_text = redacted_text + "REDACTED "
        else
            #Nope, this word is fine!
            redacted_text = redacted_text + "#{word} "
        end
}

puts redacted_text
```

You don't need to expressly say that you want to compare to every word in the redacted list, because include already does that. You should also check how to use [.each](http://perl.about.com/od/rubytutorials/a/rubyeachloop.htm).
And you don't need parenthesis for method calls, if they are simple enough.
So you could write:

```
text.split " "
```

instead of:

```
text.split(" ")
```

This was ready weird for me at first, because I came to Ruby with a C++ background. But now I use the simplified version when possible.

Comment: Amazing! Can't believe it that was simple. I was afraid I had to use a loop method or something. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Turbo get used to it. *Ruby is simple. Every single time :D*

Comment: Actually, I would use `do |word|` there instead of {|word| ...} notation for anything that doesn't fit in one line. Makes it a lot easier to read.

Comment: @atmosx Me too, but I tried to keep the syntax somewhat similar to the question to be easier to understand what was changed. I agree that `do [...] end` is more readable than `{ [...] }`

Answer (score 0):

Building on @SlySherZ's response, you could also use `map` instead of `each`

```
puts "Write something: "
text = gets.chomp.downcase          # I chained downcase here. It's simpler :D

puts "Redact some words: "
redact = gets.chomp.downcase        # Here too, same reason

words = text.split(" ")
redacted = redact.split(" ")

redacted_text = words.map{|word| redacted.include?(word) ? "REDACTED" : word }.join(" ")

puts redacted_text
```

Comment: Probably that's what he should be using... in a few weeks/months. I still find this kind of coding somewhat convoluted and harder to read.

Comment: I can see that.  I guess, as you suggested, @Turbo should check out the Ruby docs for `.each` and `.map` and see how they are similar and different.

Answer (score 0):

If you think about the problem -- removing certain patterns from the string -- it's most easily solved with regexp's (no need to split the string and loop through it yourself). Here's what I mean:

```
def remove_words(str, word_list)
    regexps = word_list.map {|word| /#{word}/}
    regexp = regexps.join('|')
    str.gsub(regexp, 'REDACTED')
end
```

Alright, but what does all of this mean? Well, first we build a regexp strings for every redacted word. The second line builds one giant regexp out of all of this, and the third actually replaces.

Answer (score 0):

Did you get an error indicating that you were missing an "end" in your code? You need 4 there.

Here is my stab at it, I check through every wordtoredact to see if it matches word, while adding to the i variable as an iterator. when you have iterated through every redactable word i will be equal to the length of redacted and add the normal word to your array. It does this while iterating through all of the words, and then joins and displays your final array at the end.

```
final_string = Hash.new

words.each do |word|         
  i = 1   
  redacted.each do |wordtoredact|
    if word == wordtoredact
      final_string << "REDACTED"
      break
    elsif i == redacted.length
      final_string << word
    end
    i+=1
  end
end

puts final_string.join(" ")
```